# JAVA_OPTS Syntax in catalina.bat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

i am trying to increase tomcat memory by adding **JAVA_OPTS** in **catalina.bat** as follows:

```
rem   TITLE           (Optional) Specify the title of Tomcat window. The default
rem                   TITLE is Tomcat if it's not specified.
rem                   Example (all one line)
rem                   set TITLE=Tomcat.Cluster#1.Server#1 [%DATE% %TIME%]
rem
rem
rem
rem $Id: catalina.bat 1146096 2011-07-13 15:20:43Z markt $
rem ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
```

but i am getting following errors in CMD when running the startup or shutdown scripts:

```
'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

please advise why i am getting them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ^
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m ^
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m ^
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC ^
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC ^
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

- You need to use the `set` command to set an environment variable.
- If you want to split a command over multiple lines in a windows bat file you need to add a `^` (caret) at the end of each line.
- No quotes necessary.

Comment: i get the error: `Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Comment: your option is incorrect. Change it to: `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Comment: i have to do the same for `-XX:CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled ^
-XX:CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`

Comment: yes, I've updated my answer. You don't need `CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled` if you have `CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing empty spaces at the end of each new line.

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8[ENTER]
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m[ENTER]
...
```

Answer (score -3):

Put backslashes at the end of lines: `\`:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m \
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m \
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC \
-XX:UseConcMarkSweepGC \
-XX:CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled \ 
-XX:CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
```